# How to use multiple strings in re.search with OR condition?

Tags: python, if-statement, search, python-re

I am using below code to search pattern in string in `if` condition but i need to use `OR` in condition..How can i do that

```
if  re.search(r'uk', result):
```

I wanted to have like below:

```
 if re.search(r'uk|eu', result):
```

but somehow its giving error

is this syntactically correct ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: code with `r'uk|eu'` works for me. You didn't show full error message so we know what is youre real problem. Maybe you have problem in different place or problem make value in different variable.

Comment: Yeah  sorry, silly mistake done, somehow missed quote in that statement....it works now with | operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if re.search(r'uk', result) or re.search(r'eu', result):
```

Comment: seems to be solution, but still not sure why that | operator which used for OR in re.search module is failing

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Tried testing the code in your question and worked fine for me - though I would write it slightly differently as `if re.search(r'(uk)|(eu)', result'):` for ease of readability (for myself at least).

Comment: my apologies yeah, i missed some quote in statement..it works now